# Vista batch for running app odd days

Tags: windows-vista, batch-file

I have read all that stuff about time saving and I wan't to create a shortcut to my IM app that won't run on odd days. It is possible in Windows Vista batch?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Do you want a shortcut that starts up your IM app on "even" days, but doesn't do anything on "odd" days? What do you mean by odd/even days - alternate days, or M/W/F/Sa vs. T/Th/Sa or something else

Comment: I want to forbid running IM on odd(or even) days by shortcut on my desktop I use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the [Windows Task Scheduler](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/appcompat/aa906020.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I'm rusty with batch files, but I think what you want to do in pseudocode is:

```
if %DAY% mod 2 = 0 then run
```

(%DAY% should return the day of the month, but remember this won't run on the 31st or the 1st, so sometimes you will be stuck without your im application for two consecutive days)